# HTML images dissappearing,not loading

Tags: html, css, image

I am saving my code and refreshing it. I dont think I did anything wrong. I am trying to make a Parallax website, I didn't add it yet because the image itself couldn't even load.
This is the code. It's not loading in any way. Completely white.

```
.img-1{
    background-image: url("Image1.jpg");
   
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}
```

Not so important but here's HTML section of it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="parallax.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="img-1">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div is of 0 height - background-image doesn't give it any height.